# how to add product comments in product display page and save in database?

Tags: magento2, product, database, quote, custom-field

I want to add product comment options in PDP and save that in database and pull back and show that in shopping cart page. How can I do it?

Comment: aren't there a existing feature of reviews in magento,

Comment: no not reviews. I wanna add a custom remark box in pdp box like "this product must delivered within 2 days."

Comment: You can add customer notes while placing the order instead of product comments.

Comment: yes I know, but our task is to add a custom comments/remarks in PDP page and save that in quote table. we are actually in training.